# search substring in a string with few fixed and rest any char

Tags: r

I have readLines from txt file.

Some line instances in text file are:

```
EAR99
EA
EAR99. NLR
EAFH9
Order Manag
```

There are more than 800 lines.

How could I find out line number which are starting with "EA***" (EA with three more alphanumeric character) substring. 
Thus in my example I should get line number:- 1,3,4. 
Line 2 is not qualified as it is on "EA".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `grep`

```
grep("^EA[[:alnum:]]{3}", lines)
#[1] 1 3 4
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines(textConnection("EAR99
EA
EAR99. NLR
EAFH9
Order Manag"))
```